# How to get first row from each group from a table in sqlitedatabase?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a table messages in my sqlite database.This table has three columns msg_id,sender_id,msg_body. I need to get one latest message with each user_id and these messages should be ordered in desc order.
for eg. my messages table is

```
 msg_id | sender_id | msg_body
--------+-----------+----------
   1    |    18     |"something"
   2    |    18     |"something"
   3    |    19     |"something"
   4    |    19     |"something"
```

What I want is table:-

```
msg_id | sender_id | msg_body
-------+-----------+----------
  4    |    19     |"something"
  2    |    18     |"something"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT sender_id, MAX(msg_id) AS max_msg_id
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY sender_id
) AS t2 ON t1.sender_id = t2.sender_id AND t1.msg_id = t2.max_msg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to do an `INNER JOIN` of your original table with a subquery containing the most recent record for each `sender_id` group:

```
SELECT t1.msg_id, t1.sender_id, t1.msg_body
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sender_id, MAX(msg_id) AS max_msg_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY sender_id
) t2
    ON t1.msg_id = t2.max_msg_id AND t1.sender_id = t2.sender_id
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

last message display for sender.

```
SELECT * FROM messagees group by sender_id order by id msg_id
```